# Mongo Find and Insert collections

Tags: mongodb

What I need is a way to insert a duplicate of another document but with some changes.
If I have this document:

```
{
    name: "jason",
    idn: "234"
}
```

After the insert of the duplicated document I would have two documents like this:

```
{
    name: "jason",
    idn: "234"
},
{
    name: "john",
    idn: "234"
}
```

I'm using MongoDB 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
const toCreate = [];
db.mydb.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    const newDoc = Object.assing({}, doc)
    delete newDoc;
    newDoc.name = `new_${newDoc.name}`;
    toCreate.push(newDoc);
});
db.mydb.insertMany(toCreate);
```